# Convert doubles to char*/string in C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers, double

I am pretty sure this is no hard task, but I don’t get what causes the problems, and I would like to really understand this, since I often have some pointer/array/cast-related problems:

I store the bounding box values in a double*

```
// this is the calss-variable
double *_boundingBox;

// this is where I put some data in it
double boundingBox[6];
boundingBox[0] = 
.
.
.
boundingBox[6] = ....; 

// set pointer to boundingbox
_boundingBox = &boundingBox;
```

and in an other class I use this

```
double* getBoundingBoxInfo()
{
    return _boundingBox;
}
```

to get my bounding box-data, which I would like to input in a QLabel as QString

```
double boundingBox[6];
boundingBox[0] = *_drawer->getBoundingBoxInfo();

std::string stringX = "x start: " <<  boundingBox[0] << "\tx end: " <<   boundingBox[3];
QLabel *labelX = new QLabel(QString(stringX.c_str()));
```

The current compile-error is

> error: invalid operands of types ‘const char [10]’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator<<’

Could someone please tell me how this should work? Am I using double*, double[] and string the way they are supposed to be used?

Comment: I think this works only with c++11. I don't think it is running on this PCs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot stream data into a `std::string` as-is. A solution is to use `std::ostringstream`:

```
std::ostringstream out;
out << "x start: " <<  boundingBox[0] << "\tx end: " <<   boundingBox[3];
std::string stringX = out.str();
```

Comment: They're actually trying to stream into a string literal.

Comment: @JosephMansfield I know, I made the "shortcut" voluntarily.

Comment: is this the "normal" way, or is there an other way I should use?

Comment: @user2699453 I guess it's common enough to deem it "normal"; it's a simple way to "convert" various data types to string (as long as they can be used with `<<`). If you have C++11, you can also look into [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Comment: ok, this worked, but now the values are wrong: "`boundingBox[0] = 1.94655e-316 boundingBox[3] = 8.29051e-316`" is the output after the getBoundingBoxInfo() and "`_boundingBox[0] = 0 _boundingBox[3] = 1`" before

Comment: @user2699453 Are you sure that you have the correct values right before building the string? In your code you seem to only assign a single value(`boundingBox[0] = *_drawer->getBoundingBoxInfo();`).

Comment: I checked it with some `std::cout` and I don't even have the right values before `return _boundingBox;`..... so I guess I mixed something up in the first code-block

Comment: @user2699453 be careful that your initial data (`double boundingBox[6];`) still exist when you use it, simply copying the address (`_boundingBox = &boundingBox;`) will not preserve data

Comment: I forgot about this... I changed `double *_boundingBox` to `double _boundingBox[6]` and now it's working in the `getBoundingBoxInfo`. Now I will take a look at how I assign the data in the third code-block

Answer (score 0):

The compilation error you're getting is for `"x start: " << boundingBox[0]`.

The type of `"x start: "` is `const char*`, and the type of `boundingBox[0]` is `double`.

But there is no definition for `operator<<(const char*,double)`.

You can get this to work by using an `ostringstream` object:

```
ostringstream oss;
oss << "x start: " << boundingBox[0] << "\tx end: " << boundingBox[3];
std::string stringX = oss.str();
```

---

As a side-note, when you set `_boundingBox = &boundingBox`, you don't need the `&`, because `boundingBox` is an array, so in essence, `boundingBox == &boundingBox`.

The reason for this (in case you were wondering) is that arrays don't have an l-value, and you cannot change the value of an array (for example, you cannot do `boundingBox = ...`).

Comment: thanks, in fact I even got an error with my line till I changed it to `_boundingBox = &boundingBox[0];`. As written before, I am not sure, if I am using pointers and arrays as I should do...

Comment: You can do `_boundingBox = (double*)boundingBox` if the compiler gives you an error for `_boundingBox = &boundingBox` (though, `_boundingBox = &boundingBox[0]` is also fine).

Answer (score 0):

QString provides everything http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#arg-20

so just use

```
QString("some text for double value: %1").arg(yourdouble, <additional parameters>)
```

and in your case:

```
... new QLabel(QString("x start: %1\tx end: %2").arg(boundingBox[0]).arg(boundingBox[3]));
```